# rails with filepicker and make image itself clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, filepicker

I'am using rails 4 with filepicker but I can't get the links to images autoclickables.

```
<% @pins.each do |pin| %>

    <!--<%#= image_tag pin.image.url(:medium) %>  -->
    <%= link_to filepicker_image_tag pin.filepicker_url, w: 200, h: 200, fit: 'clip' %><br/>
    <%= pin.description %><br/ >
```

With link_to image link's points to the view itself, not the image itself.

I'm sorry but I don't see it, some clue?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Comment: there is not redirection link , where you want to redirect it?  `<%= link_to (filepicker_image_tag pin.filepicker_url, w: 200, h: 200, fit: 'clip') , link_where _you_want %><br/>`

Comment: added the answer check it

Comment: ...fit: 'clip'), pin %> It works,I wanted to redirect it to image url's but I still mess with parentheses optional. Thank you.

Comment: could you accept the answer if it is working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it will work , you were missing url to define

```
<%= link_to (filepicker_image_tag pin.filepicker_url, w: 200, h: 200, fit: 'clip') , pin.filepicker_url %><br/>
```